# Does the ring generated by the odd power sum symmetric functions have a name?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, terminology, symmetric-functions

Let $\Lambda$ be the ring of symmetric functions and recall the *power sum symmetric function* $p_i = \sum x_1^i + x_2^i + \dots$ generate this ring. Let $\tilde\Lambda$ be the ring generated by the odd power sums. Then $\tilde\Lambda$ has several interesting properties: it satisfies the $Q$-cancellation property
$$
f(x_1,-x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = f(x_2,x_3,\dots),
$$
has the $Q$-Schur and $P$-Schur functions as orthogonal bases and is closely related to the theory of projective representations for the symmetric group.

As best I can tell (after having asked several experts), $\tilde\Lambda$ lacks a simple name. I have seen/heard people refer to it as *the ring of symmetric functions generated by the odd power sums* or *the ring of symmetric functions satisfying the $Q$-cancellation property*, but given its prominence I would have expected a name like the *__________ symmetric functions*. Is anyone aware of such a name? If someone can propose an informative name, I would be happy to start referring to $\tilde\Lambda$ as such in my future work.

Comment: Maybe create a name yourself?

Comment: @Ryan I've been tempted.

Answer (score 2):

Over a field of characteristic $0$, this is the odd subalgebra of $\left(Sym, \zeta_S\right)$, in the notation of [Marcelo Aguiar, Nantel Bergeron, and Frank Sottile, *Combinatorial Hopf algebras and generalized Dehn-Sommerville equations*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~maguiar/CHalgebra.pdf) (this link goes to a corrected postprint).

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the odd symmetric functions are by Khovanov and Ellis, and are not the ones that the OP mentioned.

Comment: @user61318: Thank you! Yes, they're a totally different thing (and I should have known that, having read much of both papers).

Answer (score 2):

Darij gave a very good reference indeed. One other instance where I saw this before is the Maple package SF, where they talk about "signed class functions" (http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/software/QFhelp.html#char2qf), this might be also useful in choosing the name, if you are so inclined.