# Do power sums determine the variables?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics

In my analysis research, I came across the following problem.  Given $n$ positive real numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, consider the $n$-many power sums
$$ p_3 = x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \dots + x_n^3 , $$
$$ p_5 = x_1^5 + x_2^5 + \dots + x_n^5 , $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ p_{2n+1} = x_1^{2n+1} + x_2^{2n+1} + \dots + x_n^{2n+1} . $$
Do the values of the power sums $p_3,p_5,\dots,p_{2n+1}$ uniquely determine $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (up to reordering)?

I was wondering if this problem exists in the literature?  I know the answer to this problem is "yes" in the case of the first $n$ power sums $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{n}$  by [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities): the power sums $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{n}$ determine the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1,\dots,e_n$ via explicit formulas, from which we can construct a degree-$n$ polynomial with roots $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and appeal to the fundamental theorem of algebra.

I believe the answer is yes, and I've checked some special cases using a computer.  Using analysis techniques I can easily get a local uniqueness statement.  Indeed, the function $f:(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (p_3,p_5,\dots,p_{2n+1})$ has a Jacobian matrix $Df$ that looks like a Vandermonde matrix, and this makes it easy to compute its determinant (and minors).  In particular, on the simplex $\{ 0 < x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n \} \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ the Jacobian matrix $Df$ has nonzero determinant, and so the inverse function theorem tells us that $f$ is locally injective.  Moreover, this argument applies to all minors of $Df$, and so $Df$ is a [strictly totally positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix) matrix.  Such matrices turn out to be diagonalizable with distinct positive eigenvalues, but I haven't been able to conclude that $f$ is globally injective.

Comment: I can prove it's true for $p_1,\dots, p_{2n-1}$, but I'm not sure about $p_3,\dots, p_{2n+1}$.

Comment: In the complex case the answer will be negative.  For instance, when $n=2$, Bezout's theorem will show that $p_3, p_5$ determine fifteen different complex choices for $x_1,x_2$ in general.

Comment: (okay, maybe 14, there seems be a point at infinity.)

Comment: It couldn't be $15$ finite points because there's an involution 
switching $x_1$ with $x_2$.  (The point at infinity $(x_1:x_2:1) = (1:-1:0)$
is indeed fixed by this involution!)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212800/does-the-ring-generated-by-the-odd-power-sum-symmetric-functions-have-a-name

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2016-85-298/S0025-5718-2015-02994-9/ seems to have relevant stuff.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay this is behind paywall (V. I. Korobov and A. N. Bugaevskaya, Almost power sum systems, Math. Comp. 85 (2016), 717-736). Would you say a word about how relevant it is?

Comment: The case $n=2$ (for positive reals) seems OK. Do you need details or do you know this case?

Comment: @YCor Amongst other things, the paper shows how to solve the version with $p_1,p_3,\ldots,p_{2n-1}$. It says there can be infinitely many solutions, though it doesn't have the positivity constraint. If you write to me at brendan.mckay(at)anu.edu.au I can give you the paper.

Comment: Applying Newton's identities allows the equations to be reduced to $n$ polynomial equations for $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$. Even for $n=3$ it isn't obvious how to solve them.

Comment: Bezout's theorem does not apply since there are infinitely many solutions in general. Noam's argument about switching $x_1$ and $x_2$ generalizes to show that for generic values the number of solutions is infinite or divisible by $n!$. This proves the Lemma 2.8 mentioned in the answer of Chris McDaniel.

Comment: The following recent paper came to mind when I saw this post and may be relevant (or maybe not, I haven’t had a chance to look carefully): https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13981

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\gamma (x) = (x^3, x^5, \dots, x^{2n+1})$. By rearranging both sides (using that all the polynomials have odd degree and therefore are antisymmetric), the problem can be restated as:

> Let $0\le a,b$, $a+b \le 2n$ integers, and $x_1, \dots x_a,y_1, \dots y_b \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. Then
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^a \gamma(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^b \gamma(y_i) $$
>
> has no nontrival solutions.

From what I can see from the [MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=309867), that is precisely the content of [1]. I haven't been able to find that paper, but I found it as a reference in [2], which also contains the idea of the proof (in a slightly more general setting) in the second half of Section 3. The key idea is using that the Jacobian matrix is a strictly totally positive matrix, indeed!

[1] J. Steinig,  *On some rules of Laguerre's, and systems of equal sums of like powers*. Rend. Mat. (6) 4 (1971), 629–644 (1972).

[2] [S. W. Drury and B. P. Marshall, *Fourier restriction theorems for degenerate curves.* Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 101(3), 541-553.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/fourier-restriction-theorems-for-degenerate-curves/7E17A1219062870146EA1D31A0DD211A)

Answer (score 6):

A related question was studied in the paper Conca, Krattenthaler, Watanabe, "Regular sequences of symmetric polynomials" Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova 121 (2009), 179-199.  The published version seems to be freely available at [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_2009__121__179_0).
For integers $a$, $n$, let $p_a(n)=x_1^a+\dotsb+x_n^a$.  Then the authors ask:  Which integers $n$ and which index sets $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ of size $n$ have the property that the sequence of power sums $p_a(n)$ with $a\in A$ form a regular sequence in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsb,x_n]$?
Here are some of their results (numbered as in the paper):

**Lemma 2.8:**  If $p_a(n)$, $a\in A$ is a regular sequence, then $n!$ must divide the product $\prod_{a\in A}a$.

**Proposition 2.9:**  If $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers, then $p_a(n)$, $a\in A$ is a regular sequence.

They also have an interesting conjecture, which is still open to my knowledge:

**Conjecture 2.10:**  If $n=3$, and if $A=\{a,b,c\}$ where $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, then $p_a(3), p_b(3), p_c(3)$ is a regular sequence if and only if
$$abc\equiv 0 \mod 6.$$

In relation to the original post:  I guess the point is that the sequence $p_a(n)$, $a\in A$ is regular if and only if the subalgebra they generate $\mathbb{C}[p_a(n); a\in A]$ is polynomial and $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsb,x_n]$ is a finite free module over it, which means that the variables are then uniquely determined by the $p_a(n)$, $a\in A$ up to choice of basis.

Comment: For another result with a similar flavor, see Problem 19 at https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7supp.pdf (version of 12/13/21; problem numbers subject to change), solution at https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7suppsol.pdf.